# Formatar moeda brasileira em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho a seguinte variável:

```
var atual = 600000.00 ;
```

Aqui temos o valor seiscentos mil no padrão americano, eu eu gostaria que quando eu imprimisse na tela ficasse assim:

```
600.000,00
```

Estou usando jquery no projeto caso ajude.

Comment: Você quer formatar ou mostrar uma validação dizendo que está incorreto?

Comment: formatar a saida

Comment: a lógica funciona em muitas linguagens <3

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Solução com `toLocaleString()`.

```js
var atual = 600000.00;

//com R$
var f = atual.toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'});

//sem R$
var f2 = atual.toLocaleString('pt-br', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});

console.log(f);
console.log(f2);
```

Comment: Excelente uso da linguagem!

Comment: O que o atributo minimumFractionDigits designa?

Comment: @RXSD, minimumFractionDigits determina que sempre mostre um mínimo de decimais, mesmo que eles não existam. O número 600.1 será formatado como 600,10.

Answer (score 16):

Eu encontrei uma solução com Reg Exp. Você usa a expressão regular para localizar os valores números e substituí-los pela formatação em Real.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = 'R$ 1.700,90';


function getMoney( str )
{
        return parseInt( str.replace(/[\D]+/g,'') );
}
function formatReal( int )
{
        var tmp = int+'';
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
        if( tmp.length > 6 )
                tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

        return tmp;
}


var int = getMoney( test );
//alert( int );


console.log( formatReal( 1000 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 19990020 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 12006 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 111090 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 1111 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 120090 ) );
console.log( formatReal( int ) );

</script>
```

Perceba que ele localiza o "valor" nesse trecho.

```
tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
```

e faz a substituição pelo valor em formato de "real brasileiro"

```
tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");
```

[Fonte](http://wbruno.com.br/expressao-regular/formatar-em-moeda-reais-expressao-regular-em-javascript/)

Answer (score 16):

Tente está função:

```html
<script language="javascript">   
function moeda(a, e, r, t) {
    let n = ""
      , h = j = 0
      , u = tamanho2 = 0
      , l = ajd2 = ""
      , o = window.Event ? t.which : t.keyCode;
    if (13 == o || 8 == o)
        return !0;
    if (n = String.fromCharCode(o),
    -1 == "0123456789".indexOf(n))
        return !1;
    for (u = a.value.length,
    h = 0; h < u && ("0" == a.value.charAt(h) || a.value.charAt(h) == r); h++)
        ;
    for (l = ""; h < u; h++)
        -1 != "0123456789".indexOf(a.value.charAt(h)) && (l += a.value.charAt(h));
    if (l += n,
    0 == (u = l.length) && (a.value = ""),
    1 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + "0" + l),
    2 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + l),
    u > 2) {
        for (ajd2 = "",
        j = 0,
        h = u - 3; h >= 0; h--)
            3 == j && (ajd2 += e,
            j = 0),
            ajd2 += l.charAt(h),
            j++;
        for (a.value = "",
        tamanho2 = ajd2.length,
        h = tamanho2 - 1; h >= 0; h--)
            a.value += ajd2.charAt(h);
        a.value += r + l.substr(u - 2, u)
    }
    return !1
}
 </script>  
 Entrar caracteres:  <br><br>
 <form>  
 Valor em R$: <input type="text" name="valor" placeholder="Digite aqui" onKeyPress="return(moeda(this,'.',',',event))">  
 </form>
```

Fonte: https://gist.github.com/antoniopassos/203181.

Comment: Olá, você poderia dar os devidos créditos ao autor do código que você usou como resposta: http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/mascara-de-moeda

Comment: O que essas notas de tecnologia tem haver com a resposta? Não tem nada haver, muito menos são necessárias, se você copiou o código de algum lugar simplesmente cite a fonte e pronto acabou, não precisa ficar justificando o seu erro com citações desnecessárias. (cc @Math)

Comment: Boa ! Me ajudou legal.

Answer (score 13):

Você pode utilizar expressões regulares para isso:

```js
function formatarMoeda() {
  var elemento = document.getElementById('valor');
  var valor = elemento.value;
  
  valor = valor + '';
  valor = parseInt(valor.replace(/[\D]+/g,''));
  valor = valor + '';
  valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");

  if (valor.length > 6) {
    valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");
  }

  elemento.value = valor;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="valor" onkeyup="formatarMoeda();" />
```

Answer (score 11):

O JavaScript tem esse método `Intl` que quase ninguém conhece. Ele não só formata número como data.

```js
const atual = 600000.00;

const valorFormatado = Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}).format(atual)

console.log(valorFormatado)
```

Comment: Olá Gilmar, que tal um pouco mais de detalhes para esclarecer sua solução?

Comment: Ja de uma breve explicação, rodar. ai que funciona. :D

Comment: Respostas aceitas são aquelas que apontam melhor o erro, descrevem a solução e se possível citam referências.

Comment: Solução limpa que funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: eu rodei aqui e retorna "R$ 600,000.00", o certo não seria "R$ 600.000,00"? Ou seja, mudar o lugar da vírgula e ponto. Pra mim essa código não funciona como esperado.

Answer (score 10):

Como a função do Sorack tem dois bugs: um de NaN ao apagar todos os números com backspace, e, outro ao digitar somente um número, o qual aparece inteiro ao invés de decimal.

Então fiz essa versão abaixo utilizando a mesma idéia, só que mais simples e que funciona em múltiplos input's.

Talvez ajude alguém.

Segue:

```js
function k(i) {
    var v = i.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
    v = (v/100).toFixed(2) + '';
    v = v.replace(".", ",");
    v = v.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.');
    i.value = v;
}
```

```html
Valor R$ <input onkeyup="k(this);" /><br/>
Valor R$ <input onkeyup="k(this);" /><br/>
Valor R$ <input onkeyup="k(this);" /><br/>
```

Clique em no botão Executar acima para testar.

Abraços

Comment: Valeu @lynx, foi a que mais me ajudou =)

Answer (score 10):

Posso estar atrasado, mas vou postar aqui como faço para formatar moedas no nodeJS.

```
num
.toFixed(2) // casas decimais
.replace('.', ',')
.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.')
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou pra mim ajudou valeu

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado por compartilhar

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma outra solução.

```js
function formatMoney(n, c, d, t) {
  c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, d = d == undefined ? "," : d, t = t == undefined ? "." : t, s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
  return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
}
console.log(formatMoney(600000.00));
console.log(formatMoney(10));
console.log(formatMoney(100));
console.log(formatMoney(0.5));
console.log(formatMoney(1500));
console.log(formatMoney(89));
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma mudança na função do Guilherme Nascimento para prefixo "R$"

```js
function moeda(a, e, r, t) {
            let n = ""
              , h = j = 0
              , u = tamanho2 = 0
              , l = ajd2 = ""
              , o = window.Event ? t.which : t.keyCode;
              a.value = a.value.replace('R$ ','');            
            if (n = String.fromCharCode(o),
            -1 == "0123456789".indexOf(n))
                return !1;
            for (u = a.value.replace('R$ ','').length,
            h = 0; h < u && ("0" == a.value.charAt(h) || a.value.charAt(h) == r); h++)
                ;
            for (l = ""; h < u; h++)
                -1 != "0123456789".indexOf(a.value.charAt(h)) && (l += a.value.charAt(h));
            if (l += n,
            0 == (u = l.length) && (a.value = ""),
            1 == u && (a.value = "R$ 0" + r + "0" + l),
            2 == u && (a.value = "R$ 0" + r + l),
            u > 2) {
                for (ajd2 = "",
                j = 0,
                h = u - 3; h >= 0; h--)
                    3 == j && (ajd2 += e,
                    j = 0),
                    ajd2 += l.charAt(h),
                    j++;
                for (a.value = "R$ ",
                tamanho2 = ajd2.length,
                h = tamanho2 - 1; h >= 0; h--)
                    a.value += ajd2.charAt(h);
                a.value += r + l.substr(u - 2, u)
            }
            return !1
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="field" placeholder="R$" onKeyPress="return(moeda(this,'.',',',event))">
```

Answer (score 1):

Apesar da pergunta já possuir uma resposta, deixo uma alternativa para as próximas pessoas que abrirem essa pergunta. Modifiquei um pouco o código do `lynx_74` para formatar o texto independentemente do comprimento de texto do input.

```
function Formatar(valor)
{
    const v = ((valor.replace(/\D/g, '') / 100).toFixed(2) + '').split('.');

    const m = v[0].split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,3}/g);

    for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        m[i] = m[i].split('').reverse().join('') + '.';

    const r = m.reverse().join('');

    return r.substring(0, r.lastIndexOf('.')) + ',' + v[1];
}
```

Se quiser pode colocar `'R$ ' + r.substring(0, r.lastIndexOf('.')) + ',' + v[1]` no retorno da função.

E mais, se quiser trabalhar com o valor depois de formatar (como enviar para uma API), você pode converter facilmente da seguinte maneira:

```
const valor = parseFloat(c.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '').replace(/[.]/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
```

Onde `c` é o valor convertido pela função `Formatar`. O 1º `replace` remove os caracteres não inclusos no intervalo `[0, 9]` e também os diferentes de `,` e `.`. O 2º `replace` troca todos os `.` por `''` e o 3º a única `,` por `.`.

Abraços!

Answer (score -1):

## Solução completa atualizada

Esta é a solução completa como função que criei baseada em cima da resposta escolhida desta pergunta do amigo Lleon:

```js
function convertToReal(number, options = {}) {
    const { moneySign = true } = options;

    if(Number.isNaN(number) || !number) return "need a number as the first parameter";

    if(typeof number === "string") { // n1
        number = Number(number);
    }

    let res;

    const config = moneySign ? {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'} : {minimumFractionDigits: 2};

    moneySign
    ? res = number.toLocaleString('pt-BR', config)
    : res = number.toLocaleString('pt-BR', config)

    const needComma = number => number <= 1000;
    if(needComma(number)) {
        res = res.toString().replace(".", ",");
    }

    return res; // n2
}

/* COMMENTS
n1: although the function returns as a string, the target value should be a 
number. Otherwise, no effect will be made.
n2: returns a string.
*/ 

const test1 = convertToReal('60.45');
const test2 = convertToReal(60.45);
const test3 = convertToReal(60.45, { moneySign: false })
const test4 = convertToReal(undefined, { moneySign: false })

console.log(test1)
console.log(test2)
console.log(test3)
console.log(test4)
```

Nesta solução, eu adicionei o tratamento de exceções para evitar falhas no seu código como - por exemplo - se o valor for uma string, então `toLocaleString` não vai funcionar, apenas se for um número.

Uma outra coisa que notei, é que valores abaixo de 1000 ainda recebem ponto em vez de vírgula. 60.0 continua assim em vez de converter para 60,0. Para garantir que isso é convertido adicionei a função `needComma` para converter valores abaixo de 1000.

Answer (score -1):

Desenvolvi essa função para se adequar a qualquer sistema monetário do mundo. Basicamente ela se aplica adicionando 3 dados importantes:

```
var decimais = 2; - Número de casas decimais após a vírgula, deixe em 0, caso queira apenas número inteiro.
var separador_milhar = '.'; - Carácter que irá separar a cada 1000 unidades
var separador_decimal = ','; - Carácter que irá separar a casa decimal
```

Segue a função abaixo:

```
function atacado(i) {
//ADD dados para a másrcara
    var decimais = 2;
  var separador_milhar = '.';
  var separador_decimal = ',';
  
  var decimais_ele = Math.pow(10, decimais);
  var thousand_separator = '$1'+separador_milhar;
  var v = i.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
    v = (v/decimais_ele).toFixed(decimais) + '';
  var splits = v.split(".");
    var p_parte = splits[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousand_separator);
  (typeof splits[1] === "undefined") ? i.value = p_parte : i.value = p_parte+separador_decimal+splits[1];
  
}
```

Segue o HTML:

```
<input onkeyup="atacado(this);" />
```

Answer (score -3):

function(value) {
if (value) {
var v = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
v = v.replace(".", ",");
v = v.replace(/,(\d)\b/g, ",$10");
v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3}),/g, "$1.$2.$3,");
v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d{3}),/g, "$1.$2,");
return v;
} else {
return '0,00'
}
}

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).