# Formatar valor em dinheiro enquanto digita com javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Existem várias perguntas no SO sobre formatação de moedas, mas a maioria nenhuma delas formata enquanto um número é digitado corretamente. Como eu posso formatar os números enquanto digita, passando nestes casos abaixo?

Por exemplo (input > output):

> 1 > 0,01
>
> 12 > 0,12
>
> 123 > 1,23
>
> 1234 > 12,34
>
> 12345 > 1.234,50
>
> 123456 > 1.234,56
>
> 123456789 > 1.234.567,89

Comment: Vc pode usar esse regex igual o user Asura Khan fez e colocar uma função .onChange no seu label: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181922/formatar-moeda-brasileira-em-javascript/181924#181924?newreg=06f97779a36346cda7edb6c52c1e7699