# Como Fazer uma máscara para campos no HTML com JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript, mask

Estava desenvolvendo um projeto simples, e precisei utilizar máscaras em um determinado formulário. Optei, naquele momento, pelo uso do [`JQuery`](https://jquery.com/) com a biblioteca [JQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dinheiro').mask('000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
});
```

Mas o JQuery está entrando em conflito com o Angular ao manipular o DOM, então tive que remover o JQuery das dependências.

De que forma posso fazer uma implementação de uma máscara com JavaScript puro?

Comment: Além da implementação nativa, uma alternativa seria o [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

Comment: Aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241620/formatar-valor-em-dinheiro-enquanto-digita-com-javascript-puro

Comment: @renanzin deu certo, mas ainda quero saber o que acontece "por baixo dos panos" em uma máscara

Comment: obs: Esse mask é muito ruim, fora que ele não funciona muito bem pra celular...

Comment: para evitar conflitos, use: `jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usei o regex que estava numa resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-validar-um-campo-que-aceita-cpf-ou-cnpj), no link o usuário que respondeu também explica a expressão regular.

```js
function validaCampo(c) {
      let valor = c.value;
      
      if(/([0-9]{2}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\/]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2})/.test(valor)) {
        c.style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
         } else {
        c.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.validable-field {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<input class="validable-field" type="text" onBlur="validaCampo(this)" placeholder="Exemplo: 000.000.000-00">

<input class="validable-field" type="text" onBlur="validaCampo(this)" placeholder="Click para dar onBlur">
```