# Como utiizar mascara de dinheiro sem jQuery

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de utilizar mascaras para dinheiro sem precisar importar o `jQuery`. Conheço a `toLocaleString` para formatar, porém gostaria de aplicar uma mascara no campo. Procurei na internet mas sem sucesso.

Tenho um `input` e gostaria de aplicar o valor do `toLocaleString` nele. No momento só capturo ele com.

```js
let salario = document.querySelector('#contract_salary');
salario.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  console.log(salario.value.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { minimumFractionDigits:2, style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }))
})
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contract_salary" name="contract_salary" required>
```

Comment: Essa daqui tá mais interessante https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181922/formatar-moeda-brasileira-em-javascript

Comment: Não tem como fazer máscara com `.toLocaleString` ao ir digitando porque ele formata o valor como um todo e não em pedaços.

Comment: Tem uma lib chamada jquery mask, muito boa.

Comment: Já tentou o SimpleMaskMoney [https://www.npmjs.com/simple-mask-money](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-mask-money)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("contract_salary").onkeyup = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var atual = document.getElementById("contract_salary").value;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }).format(atual));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="contract_salary" name="contract_salary" required>
```

Espero que tenha lhe ajudado!