# Formatar moeda para select vinda de JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esse select que carrega as opções vindas de um JSON.

Gostaria de mostrar os valores que são colocados no select no formato de Real (`999,99`) mas mesmo utilizando as funções das respostas [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181922/formatar-moeda-brasileira-em-javascript) os valores não sofrem nenhum efeito ou são mostrados no formato `999.,00`.

```js
function loadItens(){
  $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/10hz22",function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
      $("#select-iten").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+
      val.nome+" ("+ val.preco +")</option>");
    });
  });
}

loadItens();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-iten">
  <option>Selecione</option>
</select>
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar como mostrado abaixo, basicamente foi feita a conversão para `float` e depois foi utiliza a função [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
function loadItens(){
  $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/10hz22",function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
      $("#select-iten").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+
      val.nome+" ("+ parseFloat(val.preco).toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'decimal', minimumFractionDigits:2}) +")</option>");
    });
  });
}

loadItens();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-iten">
  <option>Selecione</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Que estranho, testei isso e não tinha funcionado.

Comment: Agora estou com outro problema, preciso que mostre 50,00 quando não tiver centavos e não mostre o R$, pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você não esta vendo assim no exemplo `R$ 50,00` ?

Comment: Estou, mas quando retiro a opção `{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}` aparece 50. Nesse caso específico não preciso do R$

Comment: Você não quer que mostre o `R$ `?

Comment: Isso mesmo, não quero que mostre `R$`.

Comment: É só colocar a opção `{minimumFractionDigits: 2}`. Obrigado amigo.