# Formatar moeda brasileira Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando formatar o valor monetário `R$ 3.070.499,97`. No meu banco de dados ele está salvo como "307049997", já utilizei diversas formas disponibilizadas aqui no stack-pt tanto quanto no EN e em todas as que tentei o valor é convertido para: "R$ 307.049.997,00"

Um dos tópicos que tentei: [Formatar moeda brasileira em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181922/formatar-moeda-brasileira-em-javascript)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings
Possui diversas ideias e soluções tentei adaptar algumas mas sem sucesso... Alguém pode me ajudar?
O intuito disto é exibir dentro de um gráfico o valor corretamente...

Alguns códigos tentados:

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'BRL',
      });

function formatMoney(number, decPlaces, decSep, thouSep) {
    decPlaces = isNaN(decPlaces = Math.abs(decPlaces)) ? 2 : decPlaces,
    decSep = typeof decSep === "undefined" ? "." : decSep;
    thouSep = typeof thouSep === "undefined" ? "," : thouSep;
    var sign = number < 0 ? "-" : "";
    var i = String(parseInt(number = Math.abs(Number(number) || 0).toFixed(decPlaces)));
    var j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;

    return sign +
        (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thouSep : "") +
        i.substr(j).replace(/(\decSep{3})(?=\decSep)/g, "$1" + thouSep) +
        (decPlaces ? decSep + Math.abs(number - i).toFixed(decPlaces).slice(2) : "");
}
```

E também:

```
//com R$
var f = atual.toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'});

//sem R$
var f2 = atual.toLocaleString('pt-br', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
```

[image: exemplo dos valores no gráfico]

Comment: Irei inserir no tópico! Perdão!

Comment: talvez consiga o que quer, se apenas dividir o valor da variável `number` por 100. (não converter pra inteiros [parseInt]).

Comment: O valor não está com o separador decimal, portanto refere-se à quantidade de centavos. Então precisa **dividir por 100**. Outro detalhe é que se o valor `307049997` vem como string, então precisa converter para número primeiro, ou seja, `(parseInt(atual) / 100).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'})`. Se o valor já vem como número, aí basta remover o `parseInt` (mas a divisão por 100 continua necessária)

Comment: Grato, @Danizavtz e @hkotsubo!
Com a divisão por 100 funcionou corretamente!
E, não, as respostas contidas no tópico que eu mesmo deixei o link não respondem a este adendo...

Comment: Complementando, sei que alguém vai dizer que não precisa do `parseInt` porque o JS em muitos casos converte a string automaticamente para número, mas eu prefiro deixar claro no código que ali tem uma conversão (isso também evita problemas nos casos em que a conversão automática não é feita)

Comment: @hkotsubo exato. Em meus muitos testes, se eu não passasse o parseInt ele simplesmente interpretava como uma string, portanto, sua observação do parseInt é válida!.